# Network request failed on android, however not on iOS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, expo

I have a fetch request that I'm making on an expo app, and it works flawlessly on iOS but not on android, I have this fetch request being made to an image2image api, but it keeps giving me this error.

`Network request failed at node_modules/whatwg-fetch/dist/fetch.umd.js:535:30 in setTimeout$argument_0`

I have a similar fetch request made to a text2image api that works without any problems on both platforms, I assume it might be due to the image that is being processed however I'm not sure, due to it working fine on iOS.

here's the problematic code:

```
      `if (imageResult != null){
        dispatch(setImageResult(null))
      }

      let base64Image = await uriToBase64(avatarImage);
      base64Image = base64Image.replace(/^data:image\/[a-z]+;base64,/, "");

      let response = await fetch('https://api.dezgo.com/image2image', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'X-Dezgo-Key': '// api key',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({prompt: selectedModel.prompt, init_image: base64Image, strength: 0.5, model: selectedModel.model, upscale: 2})
      });

      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${response.status}`);
      } else {
        if (imageResult != null){
          dispatch(setImageResult(null))
        }

        const blobToBase64 = (blob) => {
          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onloadend = () => resolve(reader.result);
            reader.onerror = reject;
            reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
          });
        };
        const imageBlob = await response.blob();
        let base64Image = await blobToBase64(imageBlob);
        dispatch(setImageResult(base64Image));
        dispatch(setAvatarImage(null))
        dispatch(setIsQuality(false))
      }`
```

here's the code that's similar but for text2image:

```
     `if (imageResult != null){
        dispatch(setImageResult(null))
      }

      if(selectedModelDream.prompt !== null){
        finalPrompt = (finalPrompt + ' ' + selectedModelDream.prompt)
        finalNegativePrompt = selectedModelDream.negative_prompt
      }

      let response = await fetch('https://api.dezgo.com/text2image', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'X-Dezgo-Key': '// api key',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({prompt: finalPrompt, guidance: 7, model: selectedModelDream.model, upscale: 2, width: selectedAspectRatioDream.width, height: selectedAspectRatioDream.height})
      });

      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${response.status}`);
      } else {
        if (imageResult != null){
          dispatch(setImageResult(null))
        }

        const blobToBase64 = (blob) => {
          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onloadend = () => resolve(reader.result);
            reader.onerror = reject;
            reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
          });
        };
        const imageBlob = await response.blob();
        let base64Image = await blobToBase64(imageBlob);
        dispatch(setImageResult(base64Image));
        dispatch(setIsQuality(false))
      }`
```

I've tried using axios instead, making it a form and uploading the image as an image not a base64, and nothing has worked with me, just consistently getting that same error.